# Invariant Subspaces and Differential Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

**Given**
I'm given a marginally stable system, $\dot{x}(t)=Ax(t)$, where

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & -10 & -10\cr 1 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix},$$
and $x(0)=x_o$.
The eigenvalues of the state matrix are given as
$$\lambda(A)=\{i\sqrt{10},-i\sqrt{10},-1\}$$

and the corresponding eigenvector matrix, $V$, is

$$\begin{bmatrix} -i\frac{\sqrt{10}}{10} & i\frac{\sqrt{10}}{10} & \frac{1}{10}\cr 1-i\frac{\sqrt{10}}{10} & 1+i\frac{\sqrt{10}}{10} & 0\cr 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

**Found**
I then found a set of real eigenvectors to transform the state matrix to real modal form:

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}0 & \sqrt{10} & 0\\ -\sqrt{10} & 0 & 0\\ \hline 0 & 0 & -1 \end{array} \right]$$

**Problem**
I'm now asked to use the real modal form (found above) to find two vectors of initial conditions, $x_{o_1}$ and $x_{o_2}$, such that the state trajectories $x(t)$ evolve inside the invariant plane spanned by the eigenvectors corresponding to the complex conjugate eigenvalues and the real eigenvalues, respectively. ($x_{o_1}$ is the initial condition for the complex conjugate eigenvalues and $x_{o_2}$ is the initial condition for the real eigenvalues)

I'm not sure how to proceed. I'm generally overall confused by this question. I believe the following equation is useful, but I'm not sure how to use it:

$$x(t)=\sum_{k=1}^n e^{\lambda_kt}(W_k^Tx_o)v_k$$